# Appending String to Json in Java

Tags: java, json, string

I'm appending the String into the Json and i Could see that it got appended successfully. Now i want to returnback the appended String ( entire Json)

```
public String appendSnap(String searchResultText) {
..
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parse.parse(searchResultText);
final JSONArray data = (JSONArray) obj.get("data");
final int n = data.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   final JSONObject person = (JSONObject) data.get(i);// getJSONObject(i);

   person.put("SnapURL", "https://snap.corp.com/alerts/" + (String) person.get("alertid"));

   String alertId = (String) person.get("alertid");
}
return <<not sure how to return the appended json>>
}
```

Can someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use toString:

```
return obj.toString()
```

Comment: "Body must be at least 30 characters"?

Comment: it is stackoverflow's message :(  the answer is too short